# movieClip in Array displays null, and aren't showing up on stage.addChild(Array[i])

Tags: actionscript-3, arrays, flash-cs4, addchild

I am new to Actionscript3, I need to know why I keep getting the error `Parameter child must be non-null`. And my code won't display 5 `enemyBlock` objects onto the stage but only just one.
any tips and help will be much appreciated. thanks in advance.

Returns:

```
 TypeError: Error #2007: Parameter child must be non-null.
    at flash.display::DisplayObjectContainer/addChild()
    at flash.display::Stage/addChild()
    at BlockDrop_fla::MainTimeline/EnemyBlockPos()
    at BlockDrop_fla::MainTimeline/frame2()


// declare varibles 
var isEnemyMoving:Boolean = false; 
var enemyArray:Array; 
var enemyBlock:MovieClip = new EnemyBlock(); // assign EnemyBlock class to enemyBlock
var enemyBlockMC:MovieClip; 

var count:int = 5;

var mapWidth:Number = 800;
var mapHeight:Number = 600;

function EnemyBlockPos() :void {

    // assign new MovieClip not null
    enemyBlockMC = new MovieClip;
    enemyArray = new Array();

        for(var i=1; i<= count; i++){ 
            // add class to MC
            enemyBlockMC.addChild(enemyBlock);
            // randomize position
            enemyBlock.x = Math.round(Math.random()*mapWidth);
            enemyBlock.y = Math.round(Math.random()*mapHeight);
            // set motion
            enemyBlock.movement = 5;

            // add MC to array
            enemyArray.push(enemyBlockMC);
        }


        for (var w = 1; w <= enemyArray.length; w++) {
                addChild(enemyArray[w]);
            }

} // endOf EnemyBlockPos
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ooh dude I think I have it.

Your approach is fine but I think I see where the error occurs. As far as I can see, you add an enemyBlock each time you loop to the one enemyBlockMC - Then you add that enemyBlockMC to the array (e.g.) 5 times.

therefore you'll have the 5 same referances to the enemyBlockMC in enemyArray. 
 - So you'll have enemyBlockMC the same time each itteration in your second for loop.

If you intended to have 5 different enemyBlock's on the stage you need to do something like this:

```
   for(var i:int =0; i<= count - 1; i++){ 
            // add class to MC
/*
Move this line of code into the for loop, creating a new version every time.
*/
enemyBlockMC = new MovieClip;
/*
Also move this into your loop, ensuring you make a new EnemyBlock() every time
*/
var enemyBlock:MovieClip = new EnemyBlock(); // assign EnemyBlock class to enemyBlock
enemyBlockMC.addChild(enemyBlock);
// randomize position
enemyBlock.x = Math.round(Math.random()*mapWidth);
enemyBlock.y = Math.round(Math.random()*mapHeight);
// set motion
enemyBlock.movement = 5;

// add MC to array
enemyArray.push(enemyBlockMC);
}
```

That way, every time you push `enemyBlockMC` into your enemyArray, is a new version of enemyBlock wrapped inside a movieclip.

With that said, you'll have *n*th number of enemyBlocks of which are all new versions. Therefore when you `addChild(enemyArray[w]);` in your second for loop, you'll have a new version every time.

In essence (to clarify) `enemyArray[0]` is an entirely different object to `enemyArray[2]`

Hope it makes sense. - If you need me to explain it again, just ask.

Is that what your were going for? 
Sorry about the code formatting -- o_O

Comment: yes everything on the stage works now. xD thanks heaps. wish i could upvote you more !

Comment: awe no probs dude. I'm glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

Without testing the code I notice your array, you start at one - Actionscript array are index'd from 0, resulting in your for look to be

```
for(var i:int = 0; i<= count - 1; i++){ 
        // add class to MC
...
```

and

```
for (var w:int = 0; w <= enemyArray.length -1; w++) {
...
```

Additionally (just for sanity) doing:

```
enemyArray = []
```

instead of

```
enemyArray = new Array();
```

gives you a better memory management and overhead.

See if the array counting fixes it -

Comment: yes it did, i don't get the parameter error no more. but i am still having a hard time showing my array on the stage. is my approach wrong? 
it seems that once i have place movieClips into the Array. i can't get them to show up one at a time.